# php mcrypt - decrypting and encrypting files?

Tags: php, class, encryption, pgp

I've been looking around for a php class that allows the decryption / encryption of pgp-encrypted csv files.  Everything I've found has been primarily geared towards passwords.  I'm assuming the principles are essentially the same, but was wondering if someone here can point me in the direction of a class specifically intended to receive files via FTP and decrypt them, as well as encrypt files and FTP them elsewhere?  It's my first foray into encryption, so hoping that someone can point me to something useful?  I'll keep googling, but would really appreciate some finger-pointing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mcrypt isn't designed for handling PGP-encrypted files. Best to use [GnuPG](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265) for them.

Answer (score 1):

For the PGP portion, why not just pipe to gpg.  Trying to do the encryption and other related tasks in PHP is going to be quite slow, if you can even find a class to do it.